# Julia incorrectly imports CSV with scientific notation

Tags: csv, julia

I'm using the Julia `CSV` package with `DataFrames` as sink. Some of my numbers in my csv are read incorrectly. These numbers are in scientific notation.

This row:

```
-5.871153289887625082e-01,8.095032986136727615e-01,9.900000000000006573e-01,9.900000000000006573e-01,-9.866066418838319585e-01,-3.138907529596844714e+00,-5.129218106887371675e+00,-4.803915800699462224e+00
```

results in:

```
-0.587115   │ 0.809503  │ -0.854674 │ -0.854674 │ 0.858068  │ -3.13891  │ -5.12922 │ -4.80392
```

Take note of column 3 and 4. All of a sudden they are a completely different number.

What could be going on here?

Comment: AFAIK CSV.jl uses internally an integer to represent fractional part and it seems that very long decimal part overflows it. Probably you can file an issue to CSV.jl. As a workaround if you change line 108 of float.jl in CSV package to `it = BigInt` all should work well (but the performance will be degraded).

Comment: Just to say, bug confirmed, even if `types` keyword is set to Float64. Setting to String and parsing to Float later is a valid workaround.  (or, use the built-in `readcsv` which seems to work fine with the same data)

Comment: I'll file a report in github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a reference. The issue is now fixed:

```
julia> s = """-5.871153289887625082e-01,8.095032986136727615e-01,9.900000000000006573e-01,9.900000000000006573e-01,-9.866066418838319585e-01,-3.138907529596844714e+00,-5.129218106887371675e+00,-4.803915800699462224e+00"""
"-5.871153289887625082e-01,8.095032986136727615e-01,9.900000000000006573e-01,9.900000000000006573e-01,-9.866066418838319585e-01,-3.138907529596844714e+00,-5.129218106887371675e+00,-4.803915800699462224e+00"

julia> CSV.read(IOBuffer(s), header=false)
1×8 DataFrame
│ Row │ Column1   │ Column2  │ Column3  │ Column4  │ Column5   │ Column6  │ Column7  │ Column8  │
│     │ Float64⍰  │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰  │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ -0.587115 │ 0.809503 │ 0.99     │ 0.99     │ -0.986607 │ -3.13891 │ -5.12922 │ -4.80392 │
```